# If statement is not working even statement is true

Tags: c++

My text file contain

```
Wew213
Wew214
Wew215
```

and my input in program is

```
Wew213
```

but it show me output

```
"Not Matched"
```

Actually what i am doing is i want to enter the input and if input match the number in a text file it should run the output by if statement otherwise else statement

here is my program

```
char file_data[10];
std::ifstream file_read ("D:\\myfile.txt");
cout<<"Enter the number to search"<<endl;
char val[10];
cin>>val;
while(!file_read.eof())
{
    file_read>>file_data;
    cout<<file_data<<endl;
    }
    if (val == file_data)
    {
        cout<<"Matched"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
           cout<<"Not Matched"<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `while(!eof(file))` is [always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong).

Comment: @H2CO3 I read it twice but didn't got his point , is this `while(!eof(file))` read the file one more time than it need to

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you are comparing the pointer value, which is different

you need to use [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp) to compare c string. or use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)

```
if (strcmp(val, file_data) == 0)
{
    cout<<"Matched"<<endl;
}
else
{
       cout<<"Not Matched"<<endl;
}
```

or

```
if (std::string(val) == std::string(file_data))
{
    cout<<"Matched"<<endl;
}
else
{
       cout<<"Not Matched"<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `==` test compares the addresses `val` and `file_data`. Instead of `==`, to compare the contents of the character arrays use the function `strcmp()`.

Answer (score 4):

The given code,

```
char file_data[10];
std::ifstream file_read ("D:\\myfile.txt");
cout<<"Enter the number to search"<<endl;
char val[10];
cin>>val;
while(!file_read.eof())
{
    file_read>>file_data;
    cout<<file_data<<endl;
    }
    if (val == file_data)
    {
        cout<<"Matched"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
           cout<<"Not Matched"<<endl;
    }
}
```

looks like this after running it through AStyle:

```
    char file_data[10];
    std::ifstream file_read ("D:\\myfile.txt");
    cout<<"Enter the number to search"<<endl;
    char val[10];
    cin>>val;
    while(!file_read.eof())
    {
        file_read>>file_data;
        cout<<file_data<<endl;
    }
    if (val == file_data)
    {
        cout<<"Matched"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Not Matched"<<endl;
    }
}
```

So, since the checking is done *after* the loop, checking only the *last* item read by the loop, even if you got the string comparison itself correct your program would not work.

The comparison doesn't work because, as others (rushing in) have already noted, you're comparing pointers, not strings.

To compare strings, use **`std::string`** instead of character arrays.

---

Minor correction: instead of

```
while(!file_read.eof())
```

write

```
while(!file_read.fail())
```

or just

```
while(file_read)
```

which calls `fail` for you (negating the result).

But doing this you would *also* have to check for success/failure of the input operation.

And the common idiom is to do that directly:

```
while( file_read>>file_data )
```

Answer (score 2):

The == operator will simply compare the address. You will need to use strcmp function.

Answer (score 1):

character arrays have no the comparision operator. So instead of comparing arrays theirself you are comparing addresses of first elements of the arrays.